# Drive API - file or folder access timeout

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple script to get files from Drive and print. When I run this it runs for about 400-500 seconds and I am getting timeout error.

I have two google accounts. Same script works in account-1(testing account) but not in account-2(main account).

Any help in isolating this issue would be more helpful.

Tried stepping through debugger the control comes back again and again to line-4 (file.hasNext()).  How do I debug and make this script work?

My goal: to open specific file in the drive given a file name.

```
function myHelloWorld() {
  Logger.log("Hello world\n");
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    Logger.log("There are files\n");
  }      
}
```

Note: 
1) Permission to run this script in both accounts were allowed (as part of first run).
2) No log messages were generated (View->Logs)
3) Timeout error was found in (View->Execution transcript)

Answer (score 0):

#### Code works fine

@KarthikMS - there's nothing wrong with the code. It works perfectly fine from my app: it's debugging nicely - see here:

[image: It's debugging nicely]

#### It's logging as expected

And you can also see the logs: it's running nicely too:

[image]

**The code: do you want it to iterate?**

I suspect that you want it to iterate through all the files? If so you need to use a while() statement and not an if statement. Then it will iterate through all the files. Something like this

```
while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   Logger.log(file.getName());
 }
```

**Have you given this script permission to access your google drive?**

You will need to authenticate the script to access your google drive. See here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization

I hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Permission for this script is "Has access to Google Docs, Google Drive". Also, as mentioned in the posting this works in testing account but not in 'main account'.

Comment: @KarthikMS Then i do not know the answer. but an afterthought: how many files are there in the google drive account 1 vs account 2?

Comment: testing-account has less than 100 files. But the main-account has about 500-600 files.

Comment: I was worried about time it could take to traverse, hence simplified the script to do just one check (presence or absence of file) to demonstrate the problem..

Comment: @KarthikMS hmmm I do not know the answer to this one - could it be an issue re: payments on account #2 - is there sufficient credit? That's the only other thing i can think of.

Answer (score 0):

It works okay:

Try it this way:

```
function myFiles() 
{
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()) 
  {
    var fi=files.next();
    Logger.log('FileName: %s',fi.getName());
  }      
}
```